# How do you make an iPhone beep?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What code allows me to produce a standard beep sound on the iPhone?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "standard beep" sound in iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on what kind of sound you want.

Here's how to play a sound using the AVFoundation audio framework.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

        @class AVAudioPlayer;

        @interface AudioPlayer : UIViewController {
          IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
          IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
          AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
        }

        @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
        @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
        @property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

        -(IBAction)play;
        -(IBAction)stop;

        @end

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      // Get the file path to the song to play.
      NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TNG_Theme"
                                                           ofType:@"mp3"];

      // Convert the file path to a URL.
      NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

      //Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.
      self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                               initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

      // Preloads the buffer and prepares the audio for playing.
      [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

      [filePath release];
      [fileURL release];

    }

-(IBAction)play {

  // Make sure the audio is at the start of the stream.
  self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;

  [self.audioPlayer play];

}

-(IBAction)stop {

  [self.audioPlayer stop];

}
```

Comment: Hi Fulvio,

I'm just after the standard system beep when the user presses an incorrect key.

Answer (score 1):

[AudioServicesPlaySystemSound](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound) is one thing you can do for a simple sound.

Comment: I'm just after the standard iPhone beep if the user does something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard iPhone beep"?

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by standard iPhone beep either.