# make a **beep sound** in my application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make an Iphone beep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508704/how-do-you-make-an-iphone-beep)

hi, 
i have text box and a image view.
i have two images named as CAT and DOG.
when i entered texts in my text box ,image view will display the curresponding named images.
if i entered a word that is not DOG and CAT(means: there is no image in my app same as text box value name) or there is no url found  i need to make a **beep sound**.
can any one tell me a good way to do it.
now  i am simply showing an image named as "no image". i need to make a beep sound at this situation.

Comment: This is not xcode, but cocoa-touch related. please use appropriate tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread

[How do you make an iPhone beep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508704/how-do-you-make-an-iphone-beep)

Another thread on this is

[has Iphone built in beep sound effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867058/has-iphone-built-in-beep-sound-efect)

You may also wanted to see this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUDnUAveqtU

Answer (score 3):

We can use `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class AVAudioPlayer;

@interface AudioPlayer : UIViewController {
  AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

-(IBAction)play;
-(IBAction)stop;

@end

@implementation AudioPlayer

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Get the file path to the song to play.
  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TNG_Theme"
                                                       ofType:@"mp3"];

  // Convert the file path to a URL.
  NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

  //Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.
  self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                           initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

  // Preloads the buffer and prepares the audio for playing.
  [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

  [filePath release];
  [fileURL release];
}
```

To play

```
  // Make sure the audio is at the start of the stream.
  self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
  [self.audioPlayer play];
```

To stop

```
  [self.audioPlayer stop];
```